# Bind cmd to a port AutoIT

Tags: cmd, autoit, netcat

I was wondering if anyone knows how to bind cmd.exe to port like netcat does e.g.

nc -Lp 31337 -vv -e cmd.exe

What I have been doing for this is

```
#NoTrayIcon
#Incude <Process.au3>
fileinstall("C:\nc.exe",@HomeDrive & "\nc.exe")
_RunDos(@HomeDrive & "nc -Lp 31337 -vv -e cmd.exe")
```

But I want to be able to do this without fileinstall(ing) nc.exe, because all of my computers have avast and malwarebytes. So every time they detect nc as malware and I don't want to have to add an exception to all of my computers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? There may be another way to approach the problem. I'm struggling to figure out what `-e` even does to be honest, `man nc` says it "runs the file after connecting" but what use that is I don't know.

Comment: The -e allows cmd to be execute. It kind of like ssh(ing) into the linux terminal but for windows.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid false antivirus detection you should use external UPX.
For example download one of the old ones and try.

http://upx.sourceforge.net/download/00-OLD-VERSIONS/